# Is the Google API client for javascript compatible with the Closure advanced mode compilation?

Tags: javascript, google-closure, clojurescript

Mostly, the title says it all, but I could not find any answer in the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/GettingStarted) of the library.

Specifically, can I use said library from Clojurescript ?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes, you can.

You should use [externs](http://lukevanderhart.com/2011/09/30/using-javascript-and-clojurescript.html) to describe the functions you want to use then use (:import ..) within your clojurescript code to let the compiler know that you're referring to a javascript library.

You don't need to do anything special for the Google API client, the same principles apply for using any javascript library ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953820/how-do-i-add-my-own-javascript-libs-to-clojurescript)).